# Declaring a indexer in a class example.

Tags: c#, class, indexer

When I run this program in Main() it keep giving me error messages saying that "Tommy", "Bulldog", and "Male" don't exist in current context. I couldn't figure out why? The program was running fine until I add those strings. Can anyone help me understand?

```
namespace indexusingthismethod
{
  public class Dog
  {
   private string name;
   private string breed;
   private string gender;

  public Dog()  
  { 
  name = "Fido";
  breed = "Mongrel";
  gender = "Male";
  }

  public Dog(string dogName, string dogBreed, string dogGender)
  { 
  name = dogName;
  breed = dogBreed;
  gender = dogGender;
  }
  public string Name    
  { 
  get { return name; }
  set { name = value; }
  }

  public string Breed  
  { 
    get { return breed; }
    set { breed = value; }
  }
  public string Gender
  {
   get { return gender; }
   set { gender = value; }
  }
  public string this[int index]
  {
   set
   {
      switch (index)
      {
           case 0: name = value;
               break;
           case 1: breed = value;
               break;
           case 2: gender = value;
               break;
           default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
      }
  }
  get
   {
       switch (index)
       {
           case 0: return name;
           case 1: return breed;
           case 2: return gender;
           default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
   }
 }
 public void Bark()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} said: Woof!", name);
 }
} 

public class Doggies
{
static void Main()
{

 Dog descriptionofDog = new Dog(); 
 Console.WriteLine("Dog name: {0}\nDog breed: {1}\nDog gender: {2}\n", descriptionofDog [0], descriptionofDog [1],
 descriptionofDog [2]);
 descriptionofDog[0] = Tommy;
 descriptionofDog[1] = Bulldog;
 descriptionofDog[2] = Male;

 Console.WriteLine("Dog name: {0}\nDog breed: {1}\nDog gender: {2}\n",descriptionofDog[0], descriptionofDog[1],
 descriptionofDog[2]);
```

Comment: Are they string literals? They are missing `"`s...

Comment: Trying to figure out the mistake for last 30 mins. Got it in 3 secs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Dog` has 3 string properties on it.  `Name`, `Breed` and `Gender`.

When you built up the `descriptionofDog` object, you left off the quotes which told the compiler that these are objects, not strings.

Just put quotes around your string literals:

```
descriptionofDog[0] = "Tommy";
descriptionofDog[1] = "Bulldog";
descriptionofDog[2] = "Male";
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I couldn't figure out that simple mistake.

Comment: @Rayhose, we all make them.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the @paq...'s answer. Following are the easier way to create new `Dog` object instead of using `indexer`.

```
 Dog descriptionofDog = new Dog();
```

or

```
descriptionofDog = new Dog("Tommy", "Bulldog", "Male");
```

or

```
descriptionofDog = 
 new Dog() { Name = "Tommy", Breed = "Bulldog", Gender = "Male" };
```